InteractionTimedOut: Interaction took more than 3 seconds to be responded to
Я пишу слеш команду, которая должна давать временно роль человеку. Но я столкнулся с такой проблемой что роль выдается и забирается, а Embed не присылается + выдается такая ошибка
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InteractionTimedOut: Interaction took more than 3 seconds to be responded to. Please defer it using "interaction.response.defer" on the start of your command. Later you may send a response by editing the deferred message using "interaction.edit_original_response"
Note: This might also be caused by a misconfiguration in the components make sure you do not respond twice in case this is a component.

а вот и сам код бана
@commands.slash_command()
    @commands.has_any_role(1206649047394418765)
    async def ban(self, interaction, member: disnake.Member, time: str, *, reason="Нарушения свод правил"):
        ban_role = disnake.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name="Ban")
        await member.add_roles(ban_role, reason=reason)

        timedata = {"c": 1, "d": 86_400, "m": 2_592_000}

        timeban = int(time[:-1]) * timedata[time[-1]]
        timenow = int(datetime.now().timestamp())
        timeend = timenow + timeban

        await asyncio.sleep(timeban)
        await member.remove_roles(ban_role, reason="Истек срок Бана")

        embed = disnake.Embed(
            description=f"{member.mention} получил бан",
            color=0x00ff00
        )

        embed.add_field(name="Модератор:", value=interaction.author, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Дата начала:", value=f"<t:{timenow}:f>")
        embed.add_field(name="Дата конца:", value=f"<t:{timeend}:f>")
        embed.add_field(name="Причина", value=reason)
        embed.add_field(name=f"Запросил {interaction.author}", value=interaction.author.display_avatar)

        await interaction.send(embed=embed) 

я не понимаю в чем проблема поэтому решил спросить у знающих людей
